# Firebase dynamically change orderBy type

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to create a search function as follows

```
Firebase.database.ref('database-location').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    //do some filtering on results
});
```

However i want to dynamically sort the results using either:

```
.orderByKey()
```

or

```
.orderByChild('price')
```

I tried using bracket notation to select the above (the vars are decided from an if statment):

```
var orderByType = 'orderByChild'||'orderByKey'
var orderByVal = 'price'||undefined

Firebase.database.ref('database-location')[orderByType](orderByVal).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
  //do some filtering on results
});
```

This works well  for sort by value, but when using sort by key, firebase returns an error : "Query.orderByKey failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects none."

Is there a way to dynamically remove the argument completely?
or any other way to switch between the two order by types?